# how to get the basic information of windows system

Tags: electron

I am a beginner of Electron and I wanna build an Electron App which can get the basic hardware information of a windows PC.

The text below lists what I want to get:

1. BIOS(Manufacturer , BIOS Version, release Date)
2. CPU
3. Memory,
4. Storage
5. Network
6. etc..

I have tried to use the 3rd party module(systeminformation), but the results are not what I wanted.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Actually, my main problem is I can not find a way to get BIOS information.The result I get by the module of 'systeminformation' is different from the actual BIOS version of my PC.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think that it is ok

Answer (score 0):

Below is some starter code to gather the desired information, primarily your BIOS information (as indicated in your comment).

> This will only work on a Microsoft Windows machine (tested on Windows 10).

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Import the necessary Node modules
let nodeExec = require('child_process').exec;
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

function getBios() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        nodeExec("reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) { reject(error.message); }
            if (stderr) { reject(stderr); }
            resolve(stdout);
        })
    })
}

getBios()
    .then((bios) => {
        bios = JSON.stringify(bios);
        bios = bios.replace(`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\\\HARDWARE\\\\DESCRIPTION\\\\System\\\\BIOS`, '');
        bios = bios.replace(/^"\\r\\n\\r\\n|\\r\\n\\r\\n"/g, "");
        let array = bios.split('\\r\\n');

        let temp = [];
        for (let line of array) {
            temp.push(line.trim());
        }

        bios = [];
        for (let line of temp) {
            let item = line.split('    ');
            let data = (item[2].startsWith('0x')) ? parseInt(item[2], 16) : item[2];
            bios.push({
                'name': item[0],
                'type': item[1],
                'data': data
            })
        }

        console.log(bios);
    })
```

> Even though the above code could be tidied up and optimised, it will give you the general idea about how it is acquired and manipulated.

If the registry key (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS) changes between Window versions (EG: XP, 7, 8, 10, 11, etc) then you will need to detect which version of Windows the user is using first, then use the correct registry key corresponding to that version of Windows.